# Sticky Header in Custom Lightning Page Template Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, flexipages

I've created a Custom Lightning Page Template Component as described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm

The general use of my custom template works just fine, **but** I loose the sticky highlight panels in headers of the default templates. Sticky means here, if I scroll down, the header does not scroll out of view, but sticks at the top of the page.

Using the native Templates provided by Salesforce, a Highlight Panel placed into the header region has a stick and shrinking behavior like below and this is what I would like in my Custom templates, too. Look only at the HL-Panel: it's shrinked in size and visible after the page is scrolled:

[image]

In my custom templates unfortunately I get only Highlight Panels which are not sticky, not shrinking and which are scrolling out of view, when I scroll down:

[image]

Note that I've scrolled down only a bit and the Highlight Panel is half-way out of view. Further scrolling would move the Highlight Panel including the action buttons completely out of view - which would kill usability.

**Question**

Is there any way to make the Highlight Panels sticke in Custom Custom  Lightning Page Template Components? I'm sure what I need are the right CSS-Classes in the template - but I can't find the docs for that.

**Markup**

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:recordHomeTemplate" description="...">
    <aura:attribute name="region_header"    type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="region_left"      type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="region_right"     type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <header role="banner"  class="forceHighlightsPanel"  >
        {!v.region_header}
    </header>
    <div>
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread">
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow" class="slds-m-right_small">
                {!v.region_left}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="{! $Browser.isDesktop ? '4' : '6' }" class="slds-m-left_small">
                {!v.region_right}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Design**

```
<design:component >
    <flexipage:template >
            <flexipage:region name="region_header"      defaultWidth="LARGE" />
            <flexipage:region name="region_left"        defaultWidth="LARGE" />
            <flexipage:region name="region_right"       defaultWidth="LARGE" />
       </flexipage:template>    
</design:component>
```

Comment: Following. The documentation on custom templates is still sparse and I'd still like to learn more about the quirks.

Comment: Hi Uwe, any luck with this yet?

Answer (score 6):

I tried to inspect the classes that go behind Salesforce's standard template that make the header stick, but couldn't get it to work as quickly as I preferred, so I got going with my own way. The following is not production ready, but should help you get started should you choose to go the custom route as well:

> COMPONENT:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:recordHomeTemplate" description="...">
    <aura:attribute name="region_header"    type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="region_left"      type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="region_right"     type="Aura.Component[]" />

    <aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.doneRendering}"/>

    <div id="stickySection" role="banner" class="forceHighlightsPanel">
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="false" aura:id="stickySection">
            <lightning:layoutItem>
                {!v.region_header}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
    <div>
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread">
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow" class="slds-m-right_small">
                {!v.region_left}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="{! $Browser.isDesktop ? '4' : '6' }" class="slds-m-left_small">
                {!v.region_right}
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

> CONTROLLER JS:

```
doneRendering : function(component, event, helper) {
    try {
        var stickySectionAura = component.find("stickySection");
        if(window && stickySectionAura){
            window.onscroll = function() {
                //Purely informational
                var html = document.documentElement;
                var scrollHeight = parseInt(html.scrollHeight);
                var clientHeight = parseInt(html.clientHeight);

                //This is where it happens, so adjust this per your requirement
                if(parseInt(window.pageYOffset) > 75) 
                    $A.util.addClass(stickySectionAura, 'stickySection');
                else
                    $A.util.removeClass(stickySectionAura, 'stickySection');
            }
        }
    } catch(err){
        console.log('-------> doneRendering ERROR: ' + err + ' ** MESSAGE: ' + err.message + ' ** STACK: ' + err.stack);
    }
}
```

> STYLE:

```
.THIS .stickySection {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -20px 1px 0 -24px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer

Surround your region that will contain the Highlights Panel component in the `region-header` class in your `.cmp` file. For example:

```html
<aura:component implements="lightning:recordHomeTemplate" description="...">

    <aura:attribute name="region_header"    type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <!-- additional attributes -->

    <header class="region-header">
        {!v.region_header}
    </header>
    <!-- rest of markup -->

</aura:component>
```

Here is the expected result of using that method when scrolled down. It will even perform the pretty interpolation between the standard and pinned view automatically.
[image: Result using above method.]

#### Explanation

Within the Highlight Panel component's helper, there is a function `shouldFixAndCollapseHeader` which is responsible for determining if the Highlight Panel should collapse or not (without any of your intervention). This is used in the `afterRender` event handler of the component's renderer.

In order for `shouldFixAndCollapseHeader` to return `true`, it must be able to find a parent with the class `region-header`. If it does not find a parent element with class `region-header`, then it will always return `false`.

Answer (score -1):

To make your custom highlight panel stick to the top you just need to add a simple CSS class

```
.forceHighlightsPanel {
  position: sticky;
  top: 6rem;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

`position: sticky` is supported by all recent browser versions except IE 11.

Here is also a simple how to that explains how it works https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp